# How can I show first time that getting image from firebase storage in my app?

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, firebase-storage

I define pick image and photoUrl variables:

```
    File? image;
    String? photoUrl;
```

This is my pick image method:

```
Future pickImage(ImageSource source) async {
  try {
    final image = await ImagePicker().pickImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);
    if (image == null) return;
    final imageTemporary = File(image.path);

    setState(() {
      this.image = imageTemporary;
    });
  } on PlatformException catch (e) {
    print('Failed to pick image : $e');
  }
}
```

This is my upload image function ı upload image with current user ids:

```
Future uploadFile() async {
  final path = '${_auth.currentUser!.uid}.jpg';
  final file = File(image!.path);

  final ref = FirebaseStorage.instance
      .ref()
      .child('images/${_auth.currentUser!.uid}.jpg');

  task = await ref.putFile(file);
  //final url = await ref.getDownloadURL();
  //print('Download URLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLL : $url');

  /*
   I saved download image url to setstate method

  setState(() {
    photoUrl = url.toString();
  });
  */
}
```

This is my download image and init state method, when I upload image to firebase storage first time, ı am getting no object exist at desired reference error, but after ı upload image then I try
to download image and I want to show in image.network it works, How can I fix this error when I try to upload and download first time without error ?

```
Future downloadImage() async {
    final ref = FirebaseStorage.instance
        .ref()
        .child('images/${_auth.currentUser!.uid}.jpg');

    final url = await ref.getDownloadURL();
    print('Download URLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLL : $url');

    setState(() {
      photoUrl = url.toString();
    });
  }
    
    
    
@override
  initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();

    downloadImage();
  }
```

This is my error: [image]

and [image]

this is my storage its empty :

Comment: I think you trying to get the link before the upload finishes. wait for the task to finish and add when complete to retrieve the correct link and store it in the firebase

Comment: yes you right ı guess. But ı still coudn't fix ,could you help me ?

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be that you are trying to get the url before uploading the image, Here is what you can do :

```
uploadImage() async {
final _firebaseStorage = FirebaseStorage.instance;
final _imagePicker = ImagePicker();
PickedFile image;
//Check Permissions
await Permission.photos.request();

var permissionStatus = await Permission.photos.status;

if (permissionStatus.isGranted){
  //Select Image
  image = await _imagePicker.getImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);
  var file = File(image.path);

  if (image != null){
    //Upload to Firebase
    var snapshot = await _firebaseStorage.ref()
    .child('images/imageName')
    .putFile(file).onComplete;
    var downloadUrl = await snapshot.ref.getDownloadURL();
    setState(() {
      imageUrl = downloadUrl;
    // in here you can add your code to store the url in firebase database for example:
    FirebaseDatabase.instance
        .ref('users/$userId/imageUrl')
        .set(imageUrl)
        .then((_) {
            // Data saved successfully!
        })
        .catchError((error) {
            // The write failed...
        });
            });
          } else {
            print('No Image Path Received');
          }
} else {
  print('Permission not granted. Try Again with permission access');
}
```

source [How to upload to Firebase Storage with Flutter](https://www.educative.io/answers/how-to-upload-to-firebase-storage-with-flutter)

I hope this will be helpfull

Comment: I am solved, thank you for your help Mousa Alribi :)